Op-amp Pt100 signal conditioner analysis
Long time lurker here on this forum, and now I finally feel the need to ask a probably really simple question but one that I cannot wrap my head around...
Can someone take me through how this circuit works, especially as it's intended to be used as a Pt100 conditioner.

Source: Private intranet, no more details can be given.

erisla - Hi, Since you're asking about the circuit, it doesn't appear to be your creation. Therefore, to comply with the site referencing rule, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online, please [edit] the question & add the original webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + webpage URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page etc. TY

Tips: 'op-amp' is an abbreviation of 'operational-amplifier'. It doesn't get capitalised, other than at the start of a sentence. The 'Pt' in Pt100 is the chemical symbol for platinum so only the initial letter is capitalised - although I see the answers are using 'PT'.

SamGibson, thanks, I realised this, but considering what I could add about it, it really didn't amass to anything useful, unfortunately.
Transistor, I read about this, and I agree with 'Pt', however ANSI standards apparently refers to them as Pt-100 with a dash... Nomenclature, I don't know what to make of it :)

@erisla - Thanks for the reply. Just to explain: That site rule requires us to reference to the best of our abilities. As it's not your work, there needs to be something indicating that, to avoid apparent plagiarism, so thanks for adding that line. Whether the circuit's creator (and copyright owner etc. if different) accepts the lack of any better citation, is a matter between you and them... (For future readers: Allowing this minimal reference is not setting a precedent that this will always be ok, as it causes some problems which are under consideration currently.)

Thanks Sam. As an insight to this minimal reference of mine is that the circuit is part of one of my company designs, however the designer has retired. As I have posted this, I don't consider the circuit itself to be secret or in any way advanced, hopefully it could help someone. The author, project, and title however, cannot be shared, as should be clear.

R2 and the PT100 form a voltage divider. The rest of the circuit is a non-inverting amplifier with gain of G = 1 + 33.2k/(1k||27.4k) with Vout = 0V for Vin = 2.5V*(33.2k||1k)/27.4k.
So the output voltage (after the offset) is linearly proportional to the input voltage which is 2.5V * PT100/(PT100 + 2.4k). A 0V out would occur at 88.15 ohms except the op-amp can't really sink current and go all the way to 0V without a negative supply, but that will be the intercept. Similarly the output voltage can't go all the way to the positive rail, though being a so-called rail-to-rail type it will get close if the output currents are reasonable (and they are).
This is nonlinear in terms of resistance. because of the PT100 term in the denominator. If the current was a constant 1mA (the current at T=0'C) the voltage at 100'C (138.5 ohms) would be 138.5mV but instead it is 136.4mV  (a difference of about 1.5%).
The nonlinearity in terms of resistance adds to the sensor resistance nonlinearity in terms of temperature (making it worse).

I guess that the problem I'm having is that I don't exactly understand the connection between V1, R3, R5, R4, and Vout.
As you might understand, this amplifier is connected to an ADC which has a reference voltage of 2.5V, and so 160 ohms would mean full scale. If I were to redesign this circuit to a hypothetical V1 of 5 volts, I wouldn't know how to properly size the resistors (gain).

As you can, no doubt, tell from the equations the gain and offset interact so you have to write out the algebraic expressions and solve. I guess a lazy way would be to use the equations I wrote and change the values in a spreadsheet until you got close, but where's the fun in that? You'd probably want to increase R2 to about double to keep the RTD current around 1mA.

Here is the behavior via simulation. Made with microcap v12.

~ Linear  for R2 (PT100) between ~ 85 Ohm and 160 Ohm (-40 °C < T° < +160 °C).
Conversion Resistance -> Temperature (100 Ohm -> 0 °C).
Here is the theoretical behavior. Made with Maple sheet.


Thanks for the answer. I did the simulation myself through LTSpice and achieved the same result. However the question really was on how to analyse the circuit, or let's say, how to design it in the first place. I've never seen anything like, even after some serious searching on the web.

It is very simpler. Just write the linear equations and solve. Will add in answer.
